# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__emotion_styles')

Tags: next.js, material-ui, react-hook-form, nomachine-nx

I have an NX project with nextjs app and a shared component library using MUI.

When I try to use react-hook-form in the component library like :

```
const methods = useForm()
```

I have an random error:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__emotion_styles')`.

I tried to do the same in the app/pages folder everything is working.